# Is There any aspx editor for aditing aspx page

Tags: asp.net

i want to edit aspx page using aspx editor..I dont want edit to html.can i edit direct edit aspx page without editing html

please help me
Thanks in Advnance

Comment: What do you mean by *want to edit aspx page.....I dont want edit to html*? Editing aspx markup would show you the *integrated* html as well. Do you mean editing the code behind?

Answer (score 3):

You can download and run Microsoft Visual Web Developer express for free.

http://www.microsoft.com/express/Downloads/#2010-Visual-Web-Developer

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, you will need to use some editor to edit the content of aspx pages..
there are number of free editors like HTML Editor of Ajax control toolkit, freetextbox, rich text box etc.
you can use any of it and change the content of the page.. there is an option to edit HTML or Content.. change whatever you want to change and then write back changes using System.IO :)

Happy Coding!